# Paging support in graph SDK

Tags: graph, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

Does Microsoft Graph Java SDK provide paging support for groups and users?
As Microsoft Grpah API supports paging
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

But I could not find anyhting for paging by graph SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Microsoft graph supports paging use .top() in your code. Below code is for [users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) similarly you can use for [groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```
 IUserCollectionPage users = graphClient.users()
        .buildRequest(requestOptions)
        .select("userPrincipalName,mail")
        .top(999)
        .get();
```

Comment: How to skip first 100 elements and get the response from 101-200 records

Comment: If we use graph with Odata then does it support paging?

Comment: How to ask for next 1000 records after the first lot.

Comment: Please raise new Stack overflow Question

Answer (score 0):

The .NET and JavaScript SDKs have iterator classes to make this easy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/sdks/paging